# Can't execute neither user_data script, nor remote-exec with connection block while launching ec2 instance with terraform cloud [aws-provider]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created a aws infrastructure with network acls, security group, subnets, etc [code attached at the bottom]. in the free tier. I have also established ssh connection with my ec2 instance and I can also download manually packages when logged to the instance.

However, since I want to fully utilize Terraform, I would like to pre-install some stuff while Terraform creates the instance.

The commands I want to execute are quite simple (install jdk, python, docker),

```
user_data= <<-EOF
#! /bin/bash
    echo "Installing modules..."
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
    sudo apt install -y python2.7 python-pip
    sudo apt install -y docker.io
    sudo systemctl start docker
    sudo systemctl enable docker
    pip install setuptools
    echo "Modules installed via Terraform"
EOF
```

My first approach was to utilize *user_data* parameter. Even though ec2 instance has access to the internet, none of the modules specified have been installed. Then I utilized the *remote-exec* block along with the *connection* block provided by terraform. But as many of us experienced before, terraform can't establish a successful connection to host, giving back the following messages,

*remote-exec block*

```
connection {
  type        = "ssh"
  host        = aws_eip.prod_server_public_ip.public_ip //Error: host for provisioner cannot be empty -> https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10977
  user        = "ubuntu"
  private_key = "${chomp(tls_private_key.ssh_key_prod.private_key_pem)}"
  timeout     = "1m"
}

provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "echo 'Installing modules...'",
    "sudo apt-get update",
    "sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk",
    "sudo apt install -y python2.7 python-pip",
    "sudo apt install -y docker.io",
    "sudo systemctl start docker",
    "sudo systemctl enable docker",
    "pip install setuptools",
    "echo 'Modules installed via Terraform'"
  ]
  on_failure = fail
}
```

*message of i/o timeout*

```
Connecting to remote host via SSH...
module.virtual_machines.null_resource.install_modules (remote-exec):   Host: 3.137.111.207
module.virtual_machines.null_resource.install_modules (remote-exec):   User: ubuntu
module.virtual_machines.null_resource.install_modules (remote-exec):   Password: false
module.virtual_machines.null_resource.install_modules (remote-exec):   Private key: true
module.virtual_machines.null_resource.install_modules (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
module.virtual_machines.null_resource.install_modules (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
module.virtual_machines.null_resource.install_modules (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
module.virtual_machines.null_resource.install_modules (remote-exec):   Target Platform: unix

timeout - last error: dial tcp 52.15.178.40:22: i/o timeout
```

One root of the problem that I could think of, is that I allow only 2 specific ip addresses to pass form the inbound routing of security group. So when terraform tries to connect it does so from an unknown ip to the security group. If that's the case, which is the IP address that would allow terraform to connect to my vm and pre-install packages?

[Terraform code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uCBB0rCeN0XalxIZOwQEBEpJFBY2Q5_S/view?usp=sharing) for the infrastructure.

Comment: What shows up in the server's log files when it runs the user-data script? You should look in `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/user-data.log`. Also, adding user-data to an existing EC2 instance doesn't really do anything. It is a script that runs when the server is created.

Comment: @MarkB let me check the logging of the server...The ec2 instance is created by terraform and even though there was already an instance, I slight change in the code infrastructure will recreate the instance after destroying it first.

Comment: @MarkB you are actually right..Docker and Java are indeed installed based on the syslog file. Only python didn't install because of python2.7 not being supported I guess anymore. So I guess user_data is indeed the correct approach. It's really inconvenient that I didn't know of syslogs in the first place.

Comment: What is the full code for your ec2 instance? What OS are you using exactly?

Comment: @Marcin I have uploaded the terraform code for the ec2 instance. To answer your question, I used Ubuntu - Focal 20.04 LTS

Comment: Your user_data is fine. So its not clear what is your actual issue? Is it user_data or remote_exec?

Comment: @Marcin user_data worked fine, I checked ```var/log/syslog``` as suggested from Mark B and indeed user_data run the commands. My remote-exec block from the other hand has troubles connecting to the host ip. I get a connection time-out error, even if I have given access to ssh port (inbound and outbound traffic).

Comment: You haven't provided your remote-exect block? How do you use it? What is your resource? Security groups?

Comment: @Marcin I have uploaded the terraform code (check here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uCBB0rCeN0XalxIZOwQEBEpJFBY2Q5_S/view?usp=sharing). If you can't access the link please post here and I will upload the full code in the question

Comment: Yes, it works. I will have a look.

Comment: @Marcin ok, also keep in mind that I can access remote host from my local machine using ssh connection. It's the terraform API that can't connect to host when deploying the infrastructure from terraform cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run your code in my sandbox env, and the **remote-exec works**. I had to make some changes for it to work and even to run your code (region, ami, security groups, ...). So you can have a look at the modified code and take it from there. But the code below works for me without any issues.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}



variable "prefix" {
    default="my"
}

# Create virtual private cloud (vpc)
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc_prod" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16" #or 10.0.0.0/16
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support = true

  tags = {
      Name = "production-private-cloud"
  }
}

# Assign gateway to vp
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc_prod.id

  tags = {
      Name = "production-igw"
  }
}

# ---------------------------------------- Step 1: Create two subnets ----------------------------------------
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_prod" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc_prod.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a" #data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
  depends_on        = [aws_internet_gateway.gw]

  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
      Name = "main-public-1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_prod_id2" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc_prod.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.2.0/24" //a second subnet can't use the same cidr block as the first subnet
  availability_zone = "us-east-1b" #data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[1]
  depends_on        = [aws_internet_gateway.gw]

  tags = {
        Name = "main-public-2"
    }
}

# ---------------------------------------- Step 2: Create ACL network/ rules ----------------------------------------
resource "aws_network_acl" "production_acl_network" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc_prod.id
  subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.subnet_prod.id, aws_subnet.subnet_prod_id2.id] #assign the created subnets to the acl network otherwirse the NACL is assigned to a default subnet

  tags = {
    Name = "production-network-acl"
  }
}

# Create acl rules for the network
# ACL inbound
resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "all_inbound_traffic_acl" {
  network_acl_id = aws_network_acl.production_acl_network.id
  rule_number    = 180
  protocol       = -1
  rule_action    = "allow"
  cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
  from_port      = 0
  to_port        = 0
}

# ACL outbound
resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "all_outbound_traffic_acl" {
  network_acl_id = aws_network_acl.production_acl_network.id
  egress         = true
  protocol       = -1
  rule_action    = "allow"
  rule_number    = 180
  cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
  from_port      = 0
  to_port        = 0
}

# ---------------------------------------- Step 3: Create security group/ rules ----------------------------------------
resource "aws_security_group" "sg_prod" {
    name   = "production-security-group"
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc_prod.id
}

# Create first (inbound) security rule to open port 22 for ssh connection request
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ssh_inbound_rule_prod" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 22
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"] #aws_vpc.vpc_prod.cidr_block, "0.0.0.0/0"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.sg_prod.id
  description       = "security rule to open port 22 for ssh connection"
}

# Create fifth (inbound) security rule to allow pings of public ip address of ec2 instance from local machine
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ping_public_ip_sg_rule" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 8
  to_port           = 0
  protocol          = "icmp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"] #aws_vpc.vpc_prod.cidr_block, "0.0.0.0/0"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.sg_prod.id
  description       = "allow pinging elastic public ipv4 address of ec2 instance from local machine"
}

#--------------------------------

# Create first (outbound) security rule to open port 80 for HTTP requests (this will help to download packages while connected to vm)
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "http_outbound_rule_prod" {
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 80
  to_port           = 80
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"] #aws_vpc.vpc_prod.cidr_block, "0.0.0.0/0"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.sg_prod.id
  description       = "security rule to open port 80 for outbound connection with http from remote server"
}

# Create second (outbound) security rule to open port 443 for HTTPS requests
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "https_outbound_rule_prod" {
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 443
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"] #aws_vpc.vpc_prod.cidr_block, "0.0.0.0/0"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.sg_prod.id
  description       = "security rule to open port 443 for outbound connection with https from remote server"
}

# ---------------------------------------- Step 4: SSH key generated for accessing VM ----------------------------------------
resource "tls_private_key" "ssh_key_prod" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

# ---------------------------------------- Step 5: Generate aws_key_pair ----------------------------------------
resource "aws_key_pair" "generated_key_prod" {
  key_name   = "${var.prefix}-server-ssh-key"
  public_key = tls_private_key.ssh_key_prod.public_key_openssh

  tags   = {
    Name = "SSH key pair for production server"
  }
}

# ---------------------------------------- Step 6: Create network interface ----------------------------------------

# Create network interface
resource "aws_network_interface" "network_interface_prod" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.subnet_prod.id
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.sg_prod.id]
  #private_ip      = aws_eip.prod_server_public_ip.private_ip #!!! not sure if this argument is correct !!!
  description     = "Production server network interface"

  tags   = {
    Name = "production-network-interface"
  }
}

# ---------------------------------------- Step 7: Create the Elastic Public IP after having created the network interface ----------------------------------------

resource "aws_eip" "prod_server_public_ip" {
  vpc               = true
  #instance          = aws_instance.production_server.id
  network_interface = aws_network_interface.network_interface_prod.id
  #don't specify both instance and a network_interface id, one of the two!

  depends_on        = [aws_internet_gateway.gw, aws_network_interface.network_interface_prod]
  tags   = {
    Name = "production-elastic-ip"
  }
}

# ---------------------------------------- Step 8: Associate public ip to network interface ----------------------------------------

resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
  #dont use instance, network_interface_id at the same time
  #instance_id   = aws_instance.production_server.id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.prod_server_public_ip.id
  network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.network_interface_prod.id

  depends_on = [aws_eip.prod_server_public_ip, aws_network_interface.network_interface_prod]
}

# ---------------------------------------- Step 9: Create route table with rules ----------------------------------------

resource "aws_route_table" "route_table_prod" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc_prod.id
  tags   = {
    Name = "route-table-production-server"
  }
}

/*documentation =>
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html#Add_IGW_Routing
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console#ec2-instance-connect-setup-security-group
*/

resource "aws_route" "route_prod_all" {
  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.route_table_prod.id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  depends_on             = [
    aws_route_table.route_table_prod, aws_internet_gateway.gw
  ]
}

# Create main route table association with the two subnets
resource "aws_main_route_table_association" "main-route-table" {
  vpc_id         = aws_vpc.vpc_prod.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route_table_prod.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "main-public-1-a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet_prod.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route_table_prod.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "main-public-1-b" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet_prod_id2.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route_table_prod.id
}

# ---------------------------------------- Step 10: Create the AWS EC2 instance ----------------------------------------

resource "aws_instance" "production_server" {
  depends_on                  = [aws_eip.prod_server_public_ip, aws_network_interface.network_interface_prod]
  ami                         = "ami-09e67e426f25ce0d7"
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  #key_name                    = "MyKeyPair"#aws_key_pair.generated_key_prod.key_name
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.generated_key_prod.key_name

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.network_interface_prod.id
    device_index         = 0
  }

  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"
    volume_type = "standard"
    volume_size = 8
  }

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = aws_eip.prod_server_public_ip.public_ip #Error: host for provisioner cannot be empty -> https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10977
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = tls_private_key.ssh_key_prod.private_key_pem
    timeout     = "1m"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "echo 'Installing modules...'",
      "sudo apt-get update",
      "sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk",
      "sudo apt install -y python2.7 python-pip",
      "sudo apt install -y docker.io",
      "sudo systemctl start docker",
      "sudo systemctl enable docker",
      "pip install setuptools",
      "echo 'Modules installed via Terraform'"
    ]
    on_failure = fail
  }

  #user_data= <<-EOF
        #! /bin/bash
    #echo "Installing modules..."
    #sudo apt-get update
    #sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
    #sudo apt install -y python2.7 python-pip
    #sudo apt install -y docker.io
    #sudo systemctl start docker
    #sudo systemctl enable docker
    #pip install setuptools
    #echo "Modules installed via Terraform"
    #EOF

  tags   = {
    Name = "production-server"
  }

  volume_tags = {
    Name = "production-volume"
  }
}
```

Comment: Marcin thanks for the reply and the effort to test the code. The major key spots of change between the code I have uploaded were: a) ```private_key = tls_private_key.ssh_key_prod.private_key_pem``` and b) that you accept all ip addresses from inbound security rule. I still receive the ```i/o connection timeout ip_address:22```. Could you please try the code you uploaded but this time with only accepting inbound traffic [security group] from a specific IPv4 address --like in my example

Comment: @NikSp I just tried and it also works. Maybe you are using wrong IPs in your rules?

Comment: I will check again the IPv4 address of my local machine, cause It's plugged in ethernet connection and not wifi. Maybe that change affected the IPv4 adress

Comment: @NikSp But first did you check with `0.0.0.0/0` cidrs? This way you can pin point the issue to IP address only.

Comment: No I didn't check with ```0.0.0.0/0``` will do now and keep you post, cause my IPv4 address didn't change after connecting to the internet with ethernet cable.

Comment: At least there was a progress. Having allowed all inbound traffic to ssh port gave me the following exception, ```│ timeout - last error: dial tcp 52.15.178.40:22: connect: connection refused```. Strange since we use the same code infrastructure and I have already allowed all inbound traffic.

Comment: Marcin it was because of this line ```private_key = "${chomp(tls_private_key.ssh_key_prod.private_key_pem)}"``` in the connection block. I successfully connected after making that change in the private key and letting **all inbound traffic** to *ssh port*. Probably terraform expects the private_key with the specific format. Still letting access to all ip address from ssh port is not my ideal solution.

Comment: Marcin this line ```private_key = tls_private_key.ssh_key_prod.private_key_pem``` is not a valid representation for Terraform I guess, so I reverted back to its original form (as per my code) ```private_key = "${chomp(tls_private_key.ssh_key_prod.private_key_pem)}"``` and everything worked. But still letting access to port 22 (ssh) for all IP address is not what I desire to achieve. Anyway, I will accept your answer since it resolved my question. Glad you helped me.

Comment: @NikSp Thanks. What os are you using? The. private key line in my anwser is correct, at least on Linux.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Probably it's terraform configuration that expects ```$chomp(private_key)```, so that blank spaces and lines ```\n``` be removed from the private key value. I had the same issue with azure provider.